# Static landing page refers to my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, static-pages

I'm trying to create a static landing page (for seo) which will refer to my angualrjs admin pages when users log in (the login screen & registration is part of the angular side). But the redirect is not working, I can't see the angular pages.

I've created the following folder structure:

```
 index.html (static landing page)
 -- view -- index.html (angular)
 -- view\registration\registration.html (angular)
 -- view\login\login.html (angular)
```

Am I taking the right approach? Can it be done?

Comment: Sure it can be done. Just include angular in the pages you want to use it.

Comment: "the redirect is not working" could be just about anything.  This doesn't sound like the wrong approach, but you really haven't shown anything specific.  does `view\index.html` show when you navigate to it directly?

Comment: I not recommend to you do it that, if you do this just for SEO you should to know that google can read the content now [google](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) . Anyway, your struct must look like this `public/index  public/app/index(with angular)`